# Is it normal for a 2 month old kitten to be aggressive to older ca & play in liter box?

Tags: behavior, aggression

My 5 year old cat is handicapped & the newwkitten is very aggressive to him. He can be sweet but is so hyper it climbs to top of curtains & jumps on my husband's med alert & sets it off. I really didn't realize how much stress this was going to put on my older cat! He also plays in liter box ! Please help!

Comment: Playing on the litter box is not uncommon. Being hyperactive is extremely common. It sounds like you have adopted a kitten...

Comment: I think you will find the answers here helpful: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/469/how-can-i-encourage-my-kitten-to-leave-my-adult-cat-alone?rq=1

Comment: Kala, I am closing this as a dupe of Q&A linked to by @mhwombat.  If the questions are not duplicates edit your question to indicate why it not a duplicate and we can reopen your question.